# Basic Ray Tracer

Tags: python, beginner, graphics, turtle-graphics, raytracing

This is my first self-guided programming project, and all the math used in the program is self-taught. I wanted to get a better understanding of how computer graphics worked, but I just feel more confused. Please tell me what I could do better in my next attempt programming something like this and how to learn more. Note: if you are running this code, it's not broken but takes about 40 seconds for the image to be drawn.

```
import math
import turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("My Window")
window.bgcolor(0.65, 0.65, 0.65)
window.tracer(0)
window.setup(width=1200, height=500)


turtle = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.pencolor(1, 0, 0)
turtle.pensize(0.001)

light = [60, 60, -50]

sphere = [0, 0, 101]

floorLevel = 100

radius = 100

camera = [0, 0, -100]

pixel = [20, 20, 0]


def checkIntersections_sphere(camera, pixel, sphere, radius):
    global point_of_contact
    point_of_contact = []

    a = (
        (pixel[0] - camera[0]) ** 2
        + (pixel[1] - camera[1]) ** 2
        + (pixel[2] - camera[2]) ** 2
    )

    b = (-1 * 2) * (
        (pixel[0] - camera[0]) * (sphere[0] - camera[0])
        + (pixel[1] - camera[1]) * (sphere[1] - camera[1])
        + (sphere[2] - camera[2]) * (pixel[2] - camera[2])
    )

    c = (
        (sphere[0] - camera[0]) ** 2
        + (sphere[1] - camera[1]) ** 2
        + (sphere[2] - camera[2]) ** 2
        - radius**2
    )

    d = b**2 - 4 * a * c

    if d < 0:
        point_of_contact = []
        return False
    else:
        if d == 0:
            solution_1 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
            point_of_contact = [
                camera[0] + solution_1 * (pixel[0] - camera[0]),
                camera[1] + solution_1 * (pixel[1] - camera[1]),
                camera[2] + solution_1 * (pixel[2] - camera[2]),
            ]
            return True
        else:
            solution_1 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
            solution_2 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)

            point_of_contact1 = [
                camera[0] + solution_1 * (pixel[0] - camera[0]),
                camera[1] + solution_1 * (pixel[1] - camera[1]),
                camera[2] + solution_1 * (pixel[2] - camera[2]),
            ]
            point_of_contact2 = [
                camera[0] + solution_2 * (pixel[0] - camera[0]),
                camera[1] + solution_2 * (pixel[1] - camera[1]),
                camera[2] + solution_2 * (pixel[2] - camera[2]),
            ]

            distance1 = math.sqrt(
                (point_of_contact1[0] - camera[0]) ** 2
                + (point_of_contact1[1] - camera[1]) ** 2
                + (point_of_contact1[2] - camera[2]) ** 2
            )
            distance2 = math.sqrt(
                (point_of_contact2[0] - camera[0]) ** 2
                + (point_of_contact2[1] - camera[1]) ** 2
                + (point_of_contact2[2] - camera[2]) ** 2
            )

            if distance1 < distance2:
                point_of_contact = point_of_contact1
            else:
                point_of_contact = point_of_contact2
            return True


def color(pixel, diffrence_in_angle, spector):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.pencolor(1 - diffrence_in_angle, 0 + spector, 0 + spector)
    turtle.goto(pixel[0], pixel[1])
    turtle.dot()
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.penup()


def getColor(sphere, point_of_contact):
    global diffrence_in_angle
    global spector
    global spector_1
    spector = 0
    spector_1 = 0

    normal_vector = [
        point_of_contact[0] - sphere[0],
        point_of_contact[1] - sphere[1],
        point_of_contact[2] - sphere[2],
    ]

    light_vector = [
        light[0] - point_of_contact[0],
        light[1] - point_of_contact[1],
        light[2] - point_of_contact[2],
    ]

    step_1 = (
        (normal_vector[0] * light_vector[0])
        + (normal_vector[1] * light_vector[1])
        + (normal_vector[2] * light_vector[2])
    )

    step_2 = math.sqrt(
        normal_vector[0] ** 2 + normal_vector[1] ** 2 + normal_vector[2] ** 2
    )

    step_3 = math.sqrt(
        light_vector[0] ** 2 + light_vector[1] ** 2 + light_vector[2] ** 2
    )

    step_4 = (step_1) / (step_2 * step_3)

    diffrence_in_angle = (math.acos(step_4)) / 3.14

    spector = 1 - diffrence_in_angle**0.09333


def checkFloor(camera, pixel, floorLevel):
    global floor_contact
    if pixel[1] == 0:
        return False
    else:
        t = -1 * (camera[1] + floorLevel) / (pixel[1] - camera[1])

        floor_contact = [
            camera[0] + (t * (pixel[0] - camera[0])),
            camera[1] + (t * (pixel[1] - camera[1])),
            camera[2] + (t * (pixel[2] - camera[2])),
        ]

        return True


def colorFloor(
    pixel,
):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.pencolor(0.4, 0.4, 0.4)
    turtle.goto(pixel[0], pixel[1])
    turtle.dot()
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.penup()


for x in range(-200, 200, 1):
    for y in range(-200, 200, 1):
        pixel[0] = x
        pixel[1] = y

        if checkIntersections_sphere(camera, pixel, sphere, radius):
            getColor(sphere, point_of_contact)
            color(pixel, diffrence_in_angle, spector)
        else:
            if checkFloor(camera, pixel, floorLevel):

                if checkIntersections_sphere(floor_contact, light, sphere, radius):

                    colorFloor(pixel)
sphere = [200, 0, 101]
camera = [200, 0, -100]

for x in range(50, 475, 1):
    for y in range(-200, 200, 1):
        pixel[0] = x
        pixel[1] = y

        if checkIntersections_sphere(camera, pixel, sphere, radius):
            getColor(sphere, point_of_contact)
            color(pixel, diffrence_in_angle, spector)
        else:
            if checkFloor(camera, pixel, floorLevel):

                if checkIntersections_sphere(floor_contact, light, sphere, radius):

                    colorFloor(pixel)
sphere = [-200, 0, 101]
camera = [-200, 0, -100]

for x in range(-800, 75, 1):
    for y in range(-200, 200, 1):
        pixel[0] = x
        pixel[1] = y

        if checkIntersections_sphere(camera, pixel, sphere, radius):
            getColor(sphere, point_of_contact)
            color(pixel, diffrence_in_angle, spector)
        else:
            if checkFloor(camera, pixel, floorLevel):

                if checkIntersections_sphere(floor_contact, light, sphere, radius):

                    colorFloor(pixel)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you more confused about in particular? Consider formatting your code with [Black](https://black.vercel.app) and avoiding `global`.

Comment: Im confused about how people use the graphics cards, and create different and multiple shapes in a scene. This project is the edge of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for that (and for the code formatting), but this is still hard to respond to. Without detail of what's confusing you exactly, it's not easy to offer much clarity (still plenty to offer for a general review, though).

Comment: Maybe not being exactly sure of what Im confused about is my problem lol. If you have any general advice Id be glad to take it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Overview

You've done an excellent job:

- Overall code layout is good
- You did a good job partitioning code into functions
- You leveraged code written by others with the imports
- Used meaningful names for functions and variables

Here are some adjustments for you to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Documentation

Add comments at the top of the file to state the purpose of the code.  For example:

```
'''
Draw 3 spheres.
Note: please be patient as it takes about 40 seconds to draw
the high-resolution graphics.
'''
```

### Layout

I recommend moving the functions to the top, after the `import` statements.
Having them in the middle of the code interrupts the natural flow of the
code (from a human readability standpoint).

You sometimes have blank lines where there is no need for them
and other places where they would be useful.  Consider this code:

```
for x in range(-200, 200, 1):
    for y in range(-200, 200, 1):
        pixel[0] = x
        pixel[1] = y

        if checkIntersections_sphere(camera, pixel, sphere, radius):
            getColor(sphere, point_of_contact)
            color(pixel, diffrence_in_angle, spector)
        else:
            if checkFloor(camera, pixel, floorLevel):

                if checkIntersections_sphere(floor_contact, light, sphere, radius):

                    colorFloor(pixel)
sphere = [200, 0, 101]
camera = [200, 0, -100]
```

In these nested `for` loops, I don't think you need any blank lines, but you should have one after the loops:

```
for x in range(-200, 200, 1):
    for y in range(-200, 200, 1):
        pixel[0] = x
        pixel[1] = y
        if checkIntersections_sphere(camera, pixel, sphere, radius):
            getColor(sphere, point_of_contact)
            color(pixel, diffrence_in_angle, spector)
        else:
            if checkFloor(camera, pixel, floorLevel):
                if checkIntersections_sphere(floor_contact, light, sphere, radius):
                    colorFloor(pixel)

sphere = [200, 0, 101]
camera = [200, 0, -100]
```

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Since most of the code in those nested loops is repeated 3 times (once for each
sphere), consider creating another function for that.

Another place where you repeat code is:

```
normal_vector = [
    point_of_contact[0] - sphere[0],
    point_of_contact[1] - sphere[1],
    point_of_contact[2] - sphere[2],
]
```

You can use `zip` in a list comprehension:

```
normal_vector = [p - s for p, s in zip(point_of_contact, sphere)]
```

### Naming

According to the
[PEP 8 style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names),
function and variable names should be lowercase,
with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

For example, function `colorFloor` would be `color_floor`

The `checkIntersections_sphere` function returns a boolean value.  It is customary
to name such functions with the `is_` prefix.  For example, something like
`is_point_of_contact` might be appropriate, depending on what the function does.

Similarly, `checkFloor` could be `is_floor`.

The name of `color` function could convey a little more meaning.  If the function
adds a color, it could be named `add_color`.

### Simplicity

In the following line:

```
turtle.pencolor(1 - diffrence_in_angle, 0 + spector, 0 + spector)
```

if it is not required to add 0, then the code would be simpler without it:

```
turtle.pencolor(1 - diffrence_in_angle, spector, spector)
```

Similarly:

```
b = (-1 * 2) * (
```

could be:

```
b = -2 * (
```

### Lint check

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a few issues.

It recommends adding docstrings to the functions to summarize what they do.

It also recommends minimizing the usage of global variables.

### Performance

To address your concern about the code taking longer than you would like,
I recommend you focus on the nested `for` loops and the functions that
perform a lot of calculations.

The `for` loops use a step size of 1.  Increasing the step size speeds things up,
but you lose resolution.